# Double compound component problem with Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I try to make a double composite component it is returning 'Cannot read properties of undefined reading (Label)' . As you can see, I have a composite component inside another one. The problem is that when the page loads normally and redirects to the path /login, everything works correctly, but when you refresh with f5 or access from the url it shows the above problem.

```
        <Form onSubmit={login} injectValues autoComplete="off" className={className}>
            <Form.Field name="email" required>
                <Form.Field.Label>Email</Form.Field.Label>
                <Form.Field.Input type="text" placeholder="email@domain.com" validators={[validateEmail]} />
                <Form.Field.Info />
            </Form.Field>
        </Form>
```

Inside the Form component I have the instances of the composition like this:

```
}) as ForwardRefExoticComponent<FormProps> & FormComposition;

Form.Field = Field;
Form.displayName = 'Form';
```

And inside the Form.Field component like this:

```
}) as ForwardRefExoticComponent<FieldProps> & FieldComposition;

Field.Label = Label;
Field.Input = Input;
Field.Info = Info;
Field.displayName = 'Form.Field';
```

This also happens with Form.Field.Input and Form.Field.Info.

Note that when I use only the Field.Label component or any other but without accessing from Form.Field it works normally, so the problem is with the form composition, but I can't solve it.

```
<Field.Label>Label</Field.Label> // WORKS
```

Finally I would like to add that I am redirecting from the index with the useRouter and not with the next configuration, because in the future I want to put logic there:

```
const IndexPage: NextPage = () => {
    const router = useRouter();

    if (!isServer()) {
        router.push('/login');
    }

    return null;
};
```

Comment: I haven't tried to do it in pure React, so maybe the problem is something in Next JS, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I have tried the same thing but in React without Next JS and it works without problems. In case this can help to solve the problem.